# How to use Paket restriction

Tags: paket

How do I use restrictions in Paket please?

For example, I have a `paket.dependencies` file with:

`framework: net48, net5.0, netstandard2.0`

This results in a `paket.lock` with:

`RESTRICTION: || (== net48) (== net50) (== netstandard2.0)`

So I would expect this to specify exact matches for only these frameworks is required.

Further down it has resolved a package like this:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Options (5.0) - restriction: || (&& (== net48) (>= netstandard2.1)) (== net50) (&& (== netstandard2.0) (>= netstandard2.1))`

Questions:

- Why does this even mention `netstandard2.1` when I have only specified `netstandard2.0`?
- How is the logic after `restriction:` meant to be read?

For example, the first clause `(&& (== net48) (>= netstandard2.1))` seems to say, this must be equal to .NET Framework 4.8 AND be >= .NET Standard 2.1.  But how can it be both?

Is the `||` an `or` operator?